# Partial integration in vector space

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

someone please help me solving this partial integration given below: 
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} dk_x e^{-ijk_x} \sum_m me^{imk_x} |m>\otimes |u_n(k_x)>$$
I am reading an article in which they say after partial integration of above expression one can get following expression:
$$I=\frac{1(-i)}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} dk_x \frac{\partial}{\partial k_x} \sum_m e^{i(m-j)k_x} |m>\otimes |u_n(k_x)>
+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} dk_x j e^{-ijk_x}\sum_m |m>\otimes |u_n(k_x)>+
\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} dk_x \sum_m |m>\otimes |u_n(k_x)>$$
How they come from first equation to second?

Comment: Please type your question here. If you don't want to put much effort into asking your question, why do you expect other people to make an effort to answer it?

Comment: Okay i will post it here

Comment: @zipirovich I typed my question here.